# How to display element when hover on another?

Tags: html, css, riot.js

I have tried with like below which I searched from stackoverflow , but not working yet ! This is doing on `riot.js` so I link what I tried [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3c7VXm22CmlZz1Z7IYGO?p=preview) .
I want to show `.overlay` div when hover on `#over` arrow down button but no display yet .

```
#over:hover + .overlay {
    opacity:1;
}
#over:hover > .overlay {
    opacity:1;
}
#over:hover ~ .overlay {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of those selectors work because `div.overlay` is neither a descendant nor a sibling to `div#over`.

To do what you want - with pure CSS, you would need to change the HTML structure a bit - in order to make the two div's siblings.

For example, adding `div.overlay` next to `div#over` would do the trick:

```
<h3>{Now} {opts.title}
    <div id='over'>^</div>
    <div class='overlay'>
       <li>Editable</li>
    </div>
</h3>
```

This would require following CSS rule:

```
#over:hover + .overlay {
    opacity:1;
}
```

But this would require you to adjust the absolute position of `div.overlay`. I am leaving that to you.

Here's the updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/nSNn1t0Lpuw9uUZQ1N8h?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HTML structure to achieve this in CSS and use **`~`** general sibling selector, like:

**In HTML:**

```
<div id='over'>^</div>
  <div class='overlay'>
  <div>Editable</div>
</div>
```

**In CSS:**

```
#over:hover ~ .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Have a look at the updated [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YlsXCrbpBNaCCK0t1smP?p=preview).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because two divs location are mixing up.. in mouse in/mouse out function.
try changing your css style of .overlay .

**In CSS:**

```
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    background:#000;
    color:white;
    list-style-type:none;
    right:30px;
    top:18%;
    opacity:0;
  }
```

working example here: [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WShGGvqGhReawyWE8ob2?p=preview).

also your css style float:right on #over may be problem of your mouseover function only work when u point very right of your div.